# Webscraping in R with XML Package and which Function - "Null" error

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the table "Pass Targets" from http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm into R. However, only the first two tables appear to be available.

```
> sample1 = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm", which = 1)
> sample2 = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm", which = 2)
> sample3 = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm", which = 3)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

By my count, there are 20 tables on this page, of which I'm after #14. The fact that the code works for some of the tables, and not others, leads me to think it is an issue with this specific URL.

There are shortcuts in the header on this page. So, I tried using that URL instead, but its fetches the same tables and returns the same results.

```
> sample1a = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm", which = 1)
> sample1a[1:5, ]
                                 Â             Â     1
1    via Sports Logos.net\n\tAbout logos New York Jets    6
2    via Sports Logos.net\n\tAbout logos Buffalo Bills    7
NA                                 <NA>          <NA> <NA>
NA.1                               <NA>          <NA> <NA>
NA.2                               <NA>          <NA> <NA>
    2    3    4 Final
1      14    7   10    37
2       3   14    7    31
NA   <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
NA.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
NA.2 <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
> sample1b = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm#all_vis_snap_counts", which = 1)
> sample1b[1:5, ]
                                 Â             Â     1
1    via Sports Logos.net\n\tAbout logos New York Jets    6
2    via Sports Logos.net\n\tAbout logos Buffalo Bills    7
NA                                 <NA>          <NA> <NA>
NA.1                               <NA>          <NA> <NA>
NA.2                               <NA>          <NA> <NA>
    2    3    4 Final
1      14    7   10    37
2       3   14    7    31
NA   <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
NA.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
NA.2 <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
> sample3 = readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm#all_vis_snap_counts", which = 3)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

I've read many helpful threads related to this topic. However, I felt compelled to post because this problem seems to be unique to this webpage.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like the html markup for the table is commented out which is why `readHTMLTable` can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup for the table you're looking for is commented out which is why you can't get it using `readHTMLtable`. Here's how to extract the comment, and then extract the table from the comment, using `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm")

# first get all the comments in the page
comments <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//comment()") 

# select the comment you want, convert it to text
# convert text to html, extract table node, and
# finally, convert to table
pass_targets <- comments[52] %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node("#targets_directions") %>% 
  html_table()
```

Comment: If I wanted to scrape the next table, "Rush Directions," how would I navigate there?

    > rush.directions.201609260nor = comments.201609260nor[53] %>%
    +   html_text() %>% 
    +   read_html() %>% 
    +   html_node("#targetss_directions") %>% 
    +   html_table()
    Error: ' div.table_wrapper ' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/Fantasy/Football/Football').

Comment: @DataProphets, use `rush_directions <- comments[54] %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node("#rush_directions") %>% 
  html_table()`
The key is to look at the document and at the id names of the commented-out html to know which one to select.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to view all of my possible options? If I run "comments" the list cuts out at around 20 and lists my options in code, as opposed to the ID names you reference.

Comment: You can use something like `lapply(comments, paste)` to view all the commented out html. You can also simply examine the source code for the web page to see all the comments. Html ID names are usually stored in tag names in the form of `id=id_name`.